# java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable

Tags: java, apache-spark

working with Java in Spark, I want to parse a text document called artist_data.txt;
I first created the JavaRDD;

JavaRDD rawArtistData = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/artist_data.txt");
Now to parse the document, which has Tab sperator but also has bad lines where number of the lines appear to be corrupted. They don't contain a tab,
or they inadvertently include a newline character. So I need to use flatMap method;

Now by running the code below, I got an error;
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable

```js
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, String>> artistByID0 = rawArtistData
     .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<Integer, String>>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, String>> call(String s) {
        String[] sarray = s.split("\t");
       return (Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, String>>) new Tuple2<Integer, String> 
       (Integer.parseInt(sarray[0]), sarray[1].trim());
      }
     });
   
    
    JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> artistByID = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(artistByID0);
    
    System.out.println(artistByID.count());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `flatMap` expects a List of Lists, which it will truncate the internal lists into one list. As you are splitting and parsing in one go, then you really only need the `map` function which will return the `Tuple` directly.

A more typical usecase of `flatMap` is to return the array from the split directly, which will result in all of the arrays truncated into one list so that you have all of the words instead of a bunch of separate lists of words.

Per your comment, it sounds like your code sample shown does not display your true usecase. If you have the possibility of returning nothing due to bad data, then you would want something like the following:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, String>> artistByID0 = rawArtistData
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<Integer, String>>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, String>> call(String s) {
                         String[] sarray = s.split("\t");
                         List<Tuple2<Integer, String>> returnList = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Integer, String>>();
                         if(sarray.length >= 2) 
                           returnList.add(new Tuple2<Integer, String> (Integer.parseInt(sarray[0]), sarray[1].trim()));
                         return returnList;
                        );
                    }
                });
```

Notice that this will now only return a list with items in it if the split successfully split into 2 or more items.

Comment: Hi Justin,
The problem with "map" it didn't work because the file is corrupted; the file contains the artist ID and name separated by a tab. However, a straight-
forward parsing of the file into (Int,String) tuples will fail as a small
number of the lines appear to be corrupted. They don't contain a tab,
or they inadvertently include a newline character. These lines cause a
NumberFormatException, and ideally, they would not map to anything at
all. Therefore, I should apply the flatMap function (which allows return-
ing 0, 1 or many results) to build a JavaPairRDD containing the pair (ID,
Name)

Comment: Thank you Justin, can you please help here, I am new in java and Spark world , learning ...

Comment: Justin, I think you're a bit meta for this question. He's getting type error because he's not following the API. When to use what is a good thing, but I don't think it will help this particular issue.

Comment: Hi Justin,I am getting  Cannot instantiate the type List<Tuple2<Integer,String>> Thanks a lot

Comment: @ravi666 Alot of this comes from looking at the javadocs, but I have updated my answer appropriately.

Comment: @Virmundi Actually, the OP's code did not make sense for the usecase being asked. So, rather than giving an errant answer that merely fixes the compiler error, it suggests better paths to go down. Map IS the correct answer if you're always returning one element as the code initially does. The overhead of wrapping and unwrapping lists would not be worth it.

Comment: Thank a lot Justin, I added an if condition to manage the fileds less than 2; I am getting issues with the file containing weird characters (Õ5
XÈ ÕBCpæ¡À"øÂ¥#f c`L°J5ZAdMíz Hw±TR*¾HA,Âbìe ´2`½@¬3b4iAh5Jand"0AÚ¨Ñ`É!ÈÔb*B©A)  , not sure how to skip them ...

Comment: You could wrap it in a try/catch and return the empty list if the parsing fails.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is that you've told the FlatMapFunction that you're returning a iterable of Tuple2. Apparently FlatMapFunction expects to return an iterable what you defined in the class. So easiest answer is make a LinkedList>, add just the tuple and return that.

Here is a possible change that statisfies the API.

```
public Iterable<Tuple2<Integer, String>> call(String s) {
    String[] sarray = s.split("\t");
    LinkedList<Tuple2<Integer, String>> r = new LinkedList<>();
    Tuple2<Integer, String> t = new Tuple2<Integer, String> (Integer.parseInt(sarray[0]), sarray[1].trim());
    r.add(t)
    return r;
}
```

Long answer is really a question: why not use Scala? At it's most basic it's Java. You can work your way up from there.

Comment: Thank you, but when calling FlatMapFunction it does expect Iterable; here the definition of FlatMapFunction  I found ,
package org.apache.spark.api.java.function;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * A function that returns zero or more output records from each input record.
 */
public interface FlatMapFunction<T, R> extends Serializable {
  public Iterable<R> call(T t) throws Exception;
}

Comment: Tuple2 is not Iterable. You are forcing a cast of Tuple2 to Iterable in the code above. Honestly, I'm surprised that the compiler even allows that. You need to create an Iterable of some kind. One simple, low memory version is a LinkedList.

Comment: This code sample does not make sense for FlatMap as it is expecting to always return 1 element.